# Problems understanding read()

Tags: c, linux, io

I'm not able to understand this piece of code:

```
static int read_mem(int pm, u64 *map)
{

    u64 aux = PAGE_SIZE * sizeof(*map);

    if (read(pm, map, aux) != aux) {
        pr_perror("Can't read pagemap file");
        return -1;
    }
```

It's actually reading a memory page from the descriptor pm, but I cannot understand why it is using a u64 as an address to a buffer.

How can I get the content which has been read? 
How can I print it out or process it?

Comment: It's not using a `u64` as an address. It's using a `u64 *`.

Comment: learn pointers. map is pointing to your content.

Comment: You may follow [linux/include/linux/mm_types.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.12.5/include/linux/mm_types.h#L41) to discover content of memory page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u64` is a type used in Linux whose size is 8 bytes.

> why it is using a u64 as an address to a buffer.

Your code is reading a memory page from the file descriptor `pm` which, I guess, is associated to a process memory (e.g. /proc/pid/mem/). I guess, this code is executed in x86_64 architecture where a memory location is of size 8 bytes. Therefore, a buffer pointer of type u64 is used  because this type matches the size of a memory location allowing us to handle the memory page read as big array of type u64 and size PAGE_SIZE( i.e. `u64 memory_page[PAGE_SIZE]`).

Possible problem, this code is not portable to an x86_32 architecture because u64 is 8 bytes also in 32 bit architectures while memory locations are of size 4 bytes. 
However, you should not relay on the size of the pointer to determine the size of the memory location, because, even though this method works, the standard C does not guarantee it.

> How can I get the content which has been read? How can I print it out
>   or process it?

Assuming that map points to a buffer sufficient larger to contain all the data read, you can access the value read from the memory as follows :

```
int i=0; 
puts("Memory dump"): 
for( i=0; i < PAGE_SIZE; i++) 
   printf("[%d] : %lu\n", i,  *(map+i));
```

Since the memory locations have size 8 bytes, you can see the page read as big array of type u64 and size `PAGE_SIZE`.

Comment: Hi, sounds interesting, but there appears an error: error: format â%lluâ expects argument of type âlong long unsigned intâ, but argument 3 has type âu64â [-Werror=format=]
       printf("[%d] : %llu\n", i, *(map+i));

Comment: @user2212190  It's a problem with `%llu`. The u64 is `long unsigned`. btw, that should be a waring not an error. You get an error because you are using `Werror=format`